# Need to get an id associated with the most recent column value

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

SQL QUERY

```
select id, month_id, id_type,
      max(case when immediate_prev <> id_type then immediate_prev
              end) over (partition by id, id_type, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
              ) as id_type_prev
from (select *,
            row_number() over (partition by id order by month_id) as seqnum,
            row_number() over (partition by id, id_type order by month_id) as seqnum_2,
            lag(id_type) over (partition by id order by month_id) as immediate_prev
      from `my_table`
      WHERE id = 123
        )
ORDER BY month_id asc
```

`my_table` data

```
id|month_id|id_type
123|202001|aaa
123|202002|aaa
123|202003|aaa
123|202004|bbb
123|202005|bbb
123|202006|bbb
```

Query return data

```
id|month_id|id_type|id_type_prev
123|202001|aaa|null
123|202002|aaa|null
123|202003|aaa|null
123|202004|bbb|aaa
123|202005|bbb|aaa
123|202006|bbb|aaa
```

I have a SQL query that returns the previous `id_type` value for a given id.  I would also like to know the `month_id` of the previous `id_type` but I am not sure how to get this information.  Above is the table data and what my current query returns.

Below is the additional data I am after, I woud like help getting the `month_id_prev` added to my above query.  This would be the previous `id_type`'s most recent month_id.

```
id|month_id|id_type|id_type_prev|month_id_prev
123|202001|aaa|null|null
123|202002|aaa|null|null
123|202003|aaa|null|null
123|202004|bbb|aaa|202003
123|202005|bbb|aaa|202003
123|202006|bbb|aaa|202003
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the approach below using your sample data:

```
with sample_data as (
  select 123 as id, 202001 as month_id, 'aaa' as id_type,
  union all select 123 as id, 202002 as month_id, 'aaa' as id_type,
  union all select 123 as id, 202003 as month_id, 'aaa' as id_type,
  union all select 123 as id, 202004 as month_id, 'bbb' as id_type,
  union all select 123 as id, 202005 as month_id, 'bbb' as id_type,
  union all select 123 as id, 202006 as month_id, 'bbb' as id_type,
),
cte1 as (
select id, month_id, id_type,
      max(case when immediate_prev <> id_type then immediate_prev
              end) over (partition by id, id_type, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
              ) as id_type_prev,
      latest_ym,
      lag(latest_ym) over (partition by id order by month_id) as prev_ym
from
(select *,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by month_id) as seqnum,
        row_number() over (partition by id, id_type order by month_id) as seqnum_2,
        lag(id_type) over (partition by id order by month_id) as immediate_prev,
        last_value(month_id) over (partition by id,id_type order by id) as latest_ym
from sample_data)

)

select 
  id,
  month_id,
  id_type,
  id_type_prev,
  max(if(month_id > prev_ym, prev_ym, null)) over (partition by id,id_type) as month_id_prev
from cte1
order by month_id asc
```

Output:

[image]